# Make depending slides?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Imagine I create a slide with the word "Hello" on it. On the next slide I want to add "world", so I duplicate the slide containing "Hello" and add the word "world". Now, imagine I want to change the "Hello", maybe to "Bye", then I have to update both slides manually, replacing "Hello" on each of them because I simply duplicated the "Hello" slide, there's no dependency between the "Hello" and "Hello World" slide. So, is there a better way to add content to a slide then duplicating it and making changes on the second slide?
I am on PowerPoint 2007. Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3):

It is meant for a similar purpose, but you might want to try using a [slide master](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-or-customize-a-slide-master-HA010336712.aspx) and then when you change the template, all the slides that have those properties will change as well. It can/will get clunky fast if later you decide that you don't want some slides to have that master template, but it is a start towards what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating the slide, add Animations to the first slide:

1. Add a text box with the word Hello
2. Add the word World in a second text box.
3. Now select the second text box and add an "Entrance" animation. (If you are unfamiliar with animations, a quick Google search will turn up dozens of good tutorials.) This allows the second word to be added subsequently to the first one. (For example, if you want the word to just "appear" on a mouse click, choose "Custom Animation", "Add Effect", "Entrance", "More Effects", "Appear", and set it to Start "On Click")
4. Likewise, add an "Exit" animation on the "Hello" text box
5. Add another box that says Bye right on top of the one that says hello. Add an Entrance animation on it, but this time choose a Start trigger called "With Previous", and make sure it is listed right after the Hello Exit.

[image]

Comment: This can get very complex, very quickly. It also means you can't see what the slide will look like when you are editing it without playing the animation.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to replace words it to use the replace function. Simply type in what you want to find and what you want to replace it with.

[image]

Comment: I think he wants to create a dependancy between the slides.

Comment: @soandos So, how do you create dependency between slides?

Comment: @CharlieRB That's what the OP asked, and what answers here are supposed to explain.

Comment: Hello CharlieRB, replacing Hello was just an example, there might be more complex cases (changing graphics, text position...). Also Find/Replace might hit "Hello" on other slides. So, it's really about dependencies between slides. Thanks for your try though!